# combine fct_relevel with fct_expand to create a factor order with empty factor levels

Tags: r, forcats

I have a dataset that does not contain now but later a defined order.

For instance

```r
library(tidyverse)

x <- c("a")

fct_relevel("d", c("a", "b", "c", "d"))
[1] d
Levels: d
Warning message:
3 unknown levels in `f`: a, b, and c

fct_expand("d", c("a", "b", "c", "d"))
[1] d
Levels: d a b c
```

How can I use `fct_relevel()` together with `fct_expand()` to pre-define the order in the order of the levels "a b c d" even if the levels are unknown at the current time? (Another `dplyr` solution would also be fine)

Thank you very much!

Comment: Why don't you use `factor("d", c("a", "b", "c", "d"))`?

Comment: @s_baldur's solution makes sense to me.  I appreciate the reprex, but wonder if there's more going on in your real-world use case that we're missing.  Could you tell us a bit about the context in which you want to use this?

Comment: @Adriano Mello: Thanks, this worked for me. I cannot make use of the solution of s_baldur because this also removes other factor levels that are not predefined. The argument's name however is `after`, not `before`.

Comment: @DaveArmstrong: The real-world scenario is that I would like to create a summary table with Tplyr and need to predefine the order of the variable (which I can do by setting a factor, however I do not know all the levels that might occur as I am working on data that is changing on a daily basis.

Comment: @Revan correct, `after`, thks!

Answer (score -1):

If you're working with tibbles, you can use `fct_expand` and `complete`:

```
library(forcats)

# Create am ordered factor-column
aux <- tibble(x = fct("a", c("a", "b", "c", "e")))

# Add a new level indicating where it should be
new_aux <- mutate(aux, x = fct_expand(x, "d", after = 3))

# Complete all factor cases
new_aux <- complete(new_aux, x = levels(x))

> new_aux
# A tibble: 5 × 1
  x    
  <chr>
1 a    
2 b    
3 c    
4 d    
5 e
```

Comment: @REvan here's the undeleted post.